# How to move a Heroku addon from one app to another

Tags: heroku

I am sharing a MongoDB between a few heroku apps and would like to move the ownership/billing to another app.

I have tried attaching (`heroku addons:attach`) to the receiving app and then using the `heroku addons:detach` command on the billing app, but this doesn't work.

Comment: I'm afraid this isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

Heroku support just confirmed that it is not possible to change the billing app for an add-on.

You can attach the add-on to other apps, but if you delete the original billing app then it will **instantly delete your database without warning** - even if it is attached to other active apps.

Some add-ons like Postgres offer a `fork` option, so you may be able fork, reconnect to the new instance, and delete the old database. The [Postgres fork command](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-fork#create-a-fork) looks like:

```
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:standard-0 --fork the-old-app-name::HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CHARCOAL --app the-new-app-name
```

Where `HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_CHARCOAL` is the ENV variable name of your old database on your old app.

Comment: Isn't the ENV variable name usually `DATABASE_URL`?  Anyway, the fork failed for me on my free dyno plan, `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:standard-0 --fork myapp::DATABASE_URL --app myapp-18` with the error `The database you are attempting to fork was not found.` possibly because of this Heroku advice https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-fork: "Forking is only supported on production tier database plans. Follow these steps to upgrade from a starter tier (dev or basic) plan to a production plan..."

Comment: P.S. I also tried replacing `DATABASE_URL` (which I was using literally) with its actual value e.g. `postgresql-graceful-82xx...` and got the same error. There might be some other approaches re copying the data itself which I'm going to explore next https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29753366/heroku-transfer-db-from-one-app-to-another

Comment: What if you are already using the add-on on both the old and new app, and the new app is serving prod? Can you somehow fork to the new app in that situation?