# Change Database Resource's "Billed To" App

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I have two apps in Heroku. Say app A and app B.

App A has a database resource a and app B has a database resource b.

So, something like A->a, B->b

What is happening now is that I changed app A to use database resource b that originally belong to app B. That is: A->b

App B is not in operation. Database resource a is not in use.

Currently, on app A's resource page, it shows both databases (a and b). As shown below. Note that the second database in the image is b that originally belong to app B. Therefore it has a "Billed to" B text.

[image: Database resource page]

My question is that:

1.) How could I safely make the second database resource belongs to app A as well so that it won't show as "Billed to" B on the screen?

2.) If I delete app B (as no longer needed), will the database resource b be deleted as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this thread's answer

1. you can't change billing app: [How to move a Heroku addon from one app to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51368239/how-to-move-a-heroku-addon-from-one-app-to-another)
2. yes

A bit disappointing, I know :(