# Heroku: importing from S3 failing

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to import a local Postgresql database to Heroku and I'm following these steps https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#import-to-heroku-postgres.

I have successfully:

- created a dump
- uploaded it to an S3 Bucket
- created from AWS CLI a signed link
- ran the command `heroku pg:backups:restore '<SIGNED URL>' DATABASE_URL` (adding -a with my app name).

The process to restore a backup starts correctly but then exits with this code:

```
 !    An error occurred and the backup did not finish.
 !
 !    Could not initialize transfer
 !
 !    Run heroku pg:backups:info r011 for more details.
```

Opening the log shows:

```
Database:         BACKUP
Finished at:      2020-01-09 18:49:30 +0000
Status:           Failed
Type:             Manual
Backup Size:      0.00B (0% compression)

=== Backup Logs
2020-01-09 18:49:30 +0000 Could not initialize transfer
```

I've tried:

- re-uploading the file to the bucket,
- generating a new signed link,
- putting the app in maintenance mode,
- I've created a user in my IAM management service with full S3 access and saved the credentials in the app environment as from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3

Not sure where to go from here but would appreciate any help. (I'm on the hobby plan therefore I can't ask Heroku's support for help)

Edit: I also tried:

- deleting and recreating the S3 Bucket
- installing version 1 of the AWS CLI to see if by chance the structure of a presigned link had changed

Edit 2: Since I could not find a solution I've opted to migrate the hosting entirely on AWS for the moment

Comment: please show how are you using the `pg_dump` command

Comment: From powershell: cmd /c "pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser mydb > mydb.dump"

Comment: `Could not initialize transfer` indicates heroku can't download. did you setup s3 credentials for heroku? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3

Comment: Yes, I have with the same names shown on the article, do I need to use them somewhere else? 

Also: I was under the impression that with pre-signed link authorization was given during the creation of it and it didn't depend on the receiver to have credentials, is that wrong?

Comment: might be wrong, default policy is "deny" all static access. can you just allow static requests and open your bucket for the sake of testing? create an open policy, try again, learn, and don't forget to close back the policy.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that your credentials on your machine that are stored in `~/.aws/` the default value is set to the credentials you created for your heroku configs. Then also make sure the signed url is created with those credentials and configs. I had to set my default credentials to the credentials I put in my heroku configs. Then I also had to set my default region in `~/.aws/config` to match the bucket location. Should work after that.

Here are some instructions if you are on mac or linux.
Sorry Windows people. I would assume it is something similar.

1. Create new access id and key in IAM on AWS
2. Set heroku configs to use those credentials `heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=yyy`

   - Optional (You may have to set the bucket name in heroku config too)
3. On your machine set your credentials you just created to the default in `~/.aws/credentials`
4. On your machine set your default region that corresponds to your bucket in `~/.aws/config`
5. Create signed URL `aws s3 presign s3://your-bucket-address/your-object`
6. Run restore `heroku pg:backups:restore '<SIGNED URL>' DATABASE_URL`

Comment: THIS was the key for me. My default region was set in `~/.aws/config`, but the bucket with the dumpfile was in a different region. When I lined the two up, the presigned URL started working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Had the exact same error and made these 2 adjustments. In the S3 console click on the file you want to use for the backup. You should see the name fo your file followed by 4 tabs. In the <kbd>General information</kbd> tab, do the following:

1. Click on <kbd>Make public</kbd> to make the file available for download.
2. Get the URL for that object where it says **URL of object**

   (should be something like `https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/my.file`, you can test if it works by pasting that url in a new Chrome tab and hitting that url. That should trigger the download of your file)

Once the previous check is working you can proceed to

```
heroku pg:backups restore 'https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/my.file' DATABASE_URL
```

Comment: but with this you make it public for everyone to use, I'm looking for a solution where I can pass presigned URL

Comment: You can use the presigned url with the file remaining private, but you must set the correct AWS credentials including the region to the correct bucket settings. If these were incorrect previously, you must create a new presigned URL and use that new URL to upload your file

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue and discovered the issue was that I had my bucket's region set as `us-east` rather than `us-east-1`.

Comment: Perfect, same here, just to add to this answer that you then also need to re-create a presigned url with your new aws config